# Rails allow user to set default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, default

I am working with a Rails application that allows users to create projects.  Inside these projects, users can make lists.  I am trying to figure out how to allow users to choose their "Default Working Project" from the projects index page.  This would then propagate throughout the app, showing only lists associated with the current project.  What is the best approach to making something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this easily by adding `default_working_project_id` field to your users table.

Then in your controller index set:

```
@default_working_project = current_user.default_working_project
```

In your user model add:

```
belongs_to :default_working_project, class_name: Project, foreign_key: :default_working_project_id
```

You can create your own action.  In your routes file:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get 'set_default'
  end
end
```

In your `projects_controller`:

```
def set_default
  project.find params[:id]
  current_user.default_working_project_id = project.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if current_user.save
      format.html { redirect_to projects_path } 
    else
      format.html { render 'index', notice: "your error message" }
    end
  end
end
```

In your views just add

```
link_to 'set default',  set_default_project_path(project.id)
```

**UPDATED**

To remove current default project id from user:

You can make some methods to achieve this, like:

In your Project model

If you have a relation that project belongs_to user try this.

```
def is_a_current_project?  
  self.id == self.user.default_working_project_id  
end
```

Then create an `after_destroy :remove_current_project_relation` callback method.

And the method, I recommend to add it inside your private methods:

```
def remove_current_project_relation  
  if is_a_current_project?  
   self.user.default_working_project = nil  
  end  
end
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to run the server.  I believe it is coming from the association :default_working_project.  Can you confirm this is correct, or should I make the association with my projects model?

Comment: Do you already create your column on users table?, you don't need to set relation on project by doing this.

Comment: Try removing foreing_key: :default_working_project_id on model association.

Comment: foreign_key is misspelled!

Comment: Ah!! Yes I've fallen into the copy and paste hole... It seems to be working now, however how can call upon this so that I can use a button to set the default?  I have a table that lists the projects, each with a "Set Default" button next to it.

Comment: That means that `<%= current_user.default_working_project_id %>` will display the ID of the project that is set as the default.  How could I display the Name of the project?  Also for my lists how can I cross reference them to only display for the current project?

Comment: `<%= current_user.default_working_project %>` will be a 'Project' instance object.

It has all project instance methods, if you have a name method will be 

`<%= current_user.default_working_project.name %>` same case for project.lists `<%= current_user.default_working_project.lists %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97912/discussion-between-dan-brookwell-and-aaron-castro).

Comment: how could this be used to delete the current project if that project ID is deleted by a user?

Answer (score 2):

Create a database field in `Users` table with `default_project_id` and set it.

On the model set:

```
def default_project
   return projects.find_by_id(default_project_id) if default_project_id
   false
end
```

And then, you can use something like this:

```
lists = user.default_project ? user.default_project.lists : user.lists
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I am confused as to which model I need to place `default_project` and where I place the `lists = user.default_project ? user.default_project.lists : user.lists` line.

Answer (score 1):

If only one user can see his projects and other users won't be able to see other user's projects, my suggestion is:

1. Make a boolean value `is_default` in the `projects` table. Add it with a migration.
2. Add `:is_default` to `def project_params` in the controller.
3. In the projects index page use:

   ```
   <%= render @projects %>
   ```
4. Create file `_project.html.erb` in `views/projects` folder, add to it:

   ```
   <%= form_for project, remote: true do |f| %>
       # some project data
       <%= f.check_box :is_default, class: 'project_default' %>
   <% end %>
   ```
5. In `projects_controller`:

   ```
   def update
       @project = Project.find(params[:id])
       if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
           respond_to do |format|
               format.html { redirect_to project_page } # this will run when you update project from edit page in form without 'remote: true'
               format.js # this will run if you update project with 'remote: true' form
           end
       end
   end
   ```
6. In `projects.coffee` in `assets/javascripts` folder:

   ```
   $('input.project_default').change -> $(this).closest('form').submit()
   ```
7. Create `update.js.erb` in the `views/projects` folder, add to it:

   ```
   $('#edit_project_<%= @project.id %>').replaceWith("<%= j render 'project' %>");
   ```
8. In `projects_helper`

   ```
   def current_project
       current_user.projects.find_by(is_default: true)
   end
   ```

Maybe you'll need to change these a little, based on your tasks. This solution will update projects through JavaScript.

Also it would be great to add a method in the `Project` model, which will make the previous default project not default when the user makes other project default and so on.

When you need to use lists from default project you can use `default_project.lists` in your views.